# Correlation between image render cap size and game resolution

Tags: python, game-engine

I am struggling a bit with the ImageRender. I want to built up a simulation using the Blender Game Engine in combination with ROS.

The plan is to record an image using the virtual camera in Blender (the selected one in the screenshot).

[image: Virtual Camera]

This is already working, but with a horrible resolution. The resolution of the image is currently 512x512:

[image: Output image]

My question: How can I improve the resolution of this output image?
I am getting the image using the ImageRender functionality with a plane object as a proxy where the virtual camera is rendering on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: additional info: if I increase the capsize, the image gets really messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. Capsize is limited to the window size of the BGE rasterizer.

I implemented something like:

```
import Rasterizer

windowSize = (Rasterizer.getWindowWidth(), Rasterizer.getWindowHeight())

...
imageRender.capSize = windowSize
```

Then I can start a standalone player with my desired resolution of 1600 x 1200 px and get the camera image in that very same resolution.